# Error while making requests to Quickbooks-Online

Tags: quickbooks-online

We are unable to make requests to Quickbooks online. While trying to communicate to Quickbooks API we keep on getting

General IO error while proxying request; errorCode=006003

Some sample requests:
    `https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/386413351/query?query=SELECT+*+FROM+CompanyInfo&requestid=1a91078d661245dc809f31870c4ccdb9&minorversion=1&`

`https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1280984235/query?query=SELECT+COUNT%28*%29+FROM+Item&requestid=a4569163846943379801926b21c21e81&minorversion=1&`

All of them ending in the same error message. It would be very helpful, if anyone has any clue about this.

`{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"message=General IO error while proxying request; errorCode=006003;statusCode=500","code":"6003"}],"type":"SERVICE"},"requestId":"e803880ca8d1448a9e2d87d194b08541","time":"2014-12-02T07:12:42.955Z"}`

Comment: It is known issue which doesn't have any quick fix from the client side.

Comment: hey @ManasMukherjee I am getting this same error while making 'createPayment' request. and its random. can you tell me what can be the issue? is there anything with the ratelimit?